# YouTube embed crashes Chromecast

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, chromecast, google-cast, youtube-iframe-api

I am currently building a Custom Receiver for our planned Chromecast app.
I need to display YouTube videos on the TV, alongside other photos and info that our app includes.

However, whenever a YouTube iframe embed is played on screen, after a few minutes (min 2, max 15) the Chromecast completely freezes up (including the Dev Tools debugger), and eventually just resets itself.

The issue can be reproduced every time, on multiple Chromecasts, on various videos, using this super simple test page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Youtube Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe width="1280" height="720" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4?autoplay=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or a solution to this?

The included timeline [1] shows that the iframe stops fetching frames via AJAX and shortly after the whole thing crashes.

[1] Recorded dev tools timeline: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_bgLIi2Uw5WcDBHSlpwVlJ5eFE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code and it is working.

```html
...
<div id="player" style="text-align: center"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var vid = ...;

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            playerVars: {
                videoId: vid,
                'enablejsapi': 1,
                'autoplay': 1,
                'rel': 0,
                'showinfo': 0,
                'controls': 0,
                'egm': 0,
                'showsearch': 0
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
                'onError': onError
            }
        });
    } 

</script>
...
```

You can check the the iframe api reference here:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Regards.

Comment: Answers on stackoverflow should be self-explaining and should not just contain a link. Please edit your answer.

Comment: I have tried using this method. Chromecast Reciever App still crashes. @alinaddaf, perhaps you could help?